# If a player selects the Ghost archetype, how does its body react to enviromental effects?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, archetype, undead

Assuming a human character with the Ghost archetype and no feats:

The ghost archetype specifies that the character is inmune to any effects that require a body to work. Does this include things like extreme cold, winds and the like? How "consistent" is the ghosts body?

If the body is solid enough to get pushed by strong winds, can it pick up small items like pebbles or coins?

And as a bonus question, is the ghost's body see-through?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ghosts are not affected by wind.

Starting with the specific text from incorporeal (note that the ghost archetype includes "you can't pass through solid objects unless you select the Pass Through feat"):

> An incorporeal creature or object has no physical form. It can pass through solid objects, including walls. When inside an object, an incorporeal creature can’t perceive, attack, or interact with anything outside the object, and if it starts its turn in an object, it is slowed 1. Corporeal creatures can pass through an incorporeal creature, but they can’t end their movement in its space.
>
> An incorporeal creature can’t attempt Strength-based checks against physical creatures or objects—only against incorporeal ones—unless those objects have the ghost touch property rune. Likewise, a corporeal creature can’t attempt Strength-based checks against incorporeal creatures or objects.
>
> Incorporeal creatures usually have immunity to effects or conditions that require a physical body, like disease, poison, and precision damage. They usually have resistance against all damage (except force damage and damage from Strikes with the ghost touch property rune), with double the resistance against non-magical damage.

Ghostly interactions with physical objects are a bit asymmetrical, especially for dedication ghosts. Dedication ghosts require a feat (see below) to even interact with a physical object if they don't spend ten minutes investing it with their energy, but they can still be harmed with physical objects. That said, these clauses from incorporeal make me conclude that they would not be affected by wind:

> An incorporeal creature or object has no physical form. [...] Likewise, a corporeal creature can’t attempt Strength-based checks against incorporeal creatures or objects.

Wind is not "a corporeal creature," but the intent is clear here that exerting physical force from a corporeal source on a ghost does not work (as long as it doesn't have ghost touch), which is what wind does. Lacking a physical form and being immune to strength-based checks means that wind is unable to push the ghost. Cold (from said wind) would similarly not affect the ghost.

Ambient temperature and similar environmental circumstances are a bit more nebulous: an argument can be made that *any* temperature gradient requires a physical body and thus ambient heat/cold would never affect a ghost, but this may come down to DM adjudication. The lines start getting a bit blurry once you're past what would generally be considered a "physical" effect like poison or bodily contact.

### Ghosts cannot pick up or interact with objects (without a feat).

> If the body is solid enough to get pushed by strong winds, can it pick up small items like pebbles or coins?

There is a dedication feat, [Ghostly Grasp](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3499), that includes the following:

> You gain the advanced undead benefits and can interact with physical objects, with limits. You can attempt Strength-based skill checks against physical creatures and objects. You can Interact with physical objects, but the action has no effect unless you succeed at a DC 20 Athletics or DC 20 Thievery check.

Dedication ghosts cannot pick up small items without either investing them or taking this feat.

### Ghosts are at most translucent (by default).

> And as a bonus question, is the ghost's body see-through?

Ghosts are "a spirit of mist and anguish" which may make them translucent, depending on how dense the mist is. More importantly, they're not see-through in terms of being invisible, in this instance due to [a special ability of ghosts, fade](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=51), which is not available to dedication ghosts:

> The ghost becomes invisible until the beginning of its next turn.

Since they require a special ability and an action to turn invisible, they must not be invisible by default. As there are no stated bonuses to stealth from either being a ghost or being incorporeal, their translucency would provide no inherent bonuses.

Comment: That's fair; I'd left it out partially because I thought it may require adjudication, but I can just explicitly say that rather than dancing around it.